# How can one manage the access of a book created using GitBook?

Tags: authentication, github, oauth-2.0, gitbook, access-keys

I have created a book using GitBook. I want only specific set of people to be able to read my book. These set of people should be able to access it by logging in somewhere or by any other method. How shall I achieve this?
Even if the link is public, how shall I restrict the users who see it?
(I don't want to add them in the collaborators list)

Answer (score 0):

As mention in "[How can I grant read-only access to a private book?](https://help.gitbook.com/books/how-can-i-grant-read-access.html) "

> There are two ways to grant read-only access to a private book:
>
> - by inviting him as Collaborator, or
> - by creating an **[Access Key](https://help.gitbook.com/books/what-is-an-access-key.html)**.

So in your case, providing your book is private (private GitHub repo), an access key is a solution, but you cannot easily control the set of people using it; ie: you can only control the set you are giving the token to.
So that means you have to provide your own front-end, with user account management, in order to give access to the book. But GitBook itself does not have such mechanism.